# JBoss7 - JBAS015801: Invalid option

Tags: java, jboss

Olá, alguém sabe como posso resolver este problema?

Já instalei o avast e resolvi o problema do "virus" na minha máquina, mas agora não consigo iniciar o JBoss.

```
14:31:07,232 INFORMAÇÕES [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
JBAS015801: Invalid option 'http://www.seekmx.com/?bd=hp&oem=hprotect&uid=WDCXWD3200BPVT-22ZEST0_WD-WXD1AC0C4075C4075&version=1.0.0.1&pid=3662073653&cs='Usage: ./standalone.sh [args...]
```

Obrigado

Comment: Configurou certo o standalone.xml?

Comment: Pois é... eu olhei o standalone.xml mas não achei nada de diferente... Eu não entendi de onde o JBoss está encontrando esse seekmx. Seria alguma configuração do windows? valeuuu

Comment: Não encontrei nada parecido por enquanto cara.

Comment: Estranho né... acabei de excluir a pasta do JBoss e baixei denovo... Continua a mesma coisa. Por isso penso que pode ser alguma variável do sistema operacional algo assim... Mas também não achei nada. de qualquer forma muito obrigado.

Comment: jaja aparece alguém pra responder, vou acompanhar a pergunta.

Comment: Amigo, reiniciei o computador mais uma vez e agora o JBoss inicial normalmente. É algo de errado com meu computador mesmo, por isso não encontramos respostas no google. Valeu mais uma vez...